# How to extract specific words from a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I have to extract two things from a string: A list that contains stop-words, and another list that contains the rest of the string.

```
text = 'he is the best when people in our life'

stopwords = ['he', 'the', 'our']

contains_stopwords = []
normal_words = []
for i in text.split():
    for j in stopwords:
        if i in j:
            contains_stopwords.append(i)
        else:
            normal_words.append(i)
if text.split() in stopwords:
    contains_stopwords.append(text.split())
else:
    normal_words.append(text.split())

print("contains_stopwords:", contains_stopwords)
print("normal_words:", normal_words)
```

Output:

```
contains_stopwords: ['he', 'he', 'the', 'our']
normal_words: ['he', 'is', 'is', 'is', 'the', 'the', 'best', 'best', 'best', 'when', 'when', 'when', 'people', 'people', 'people', 'in', 'in', 'in', 'our', 'our', 'life', 'life', 'life', ['he', 'is', 'the', 'best', 'when', 'people', 'in', 'our', 'life']]
```

Desired result:

```
contains_stopwords: ['he', 'the', 'our']
normal_words: ['is', 'best', 'when', 'people', 'in', 'life']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One answer could be:

```py
text = 'he is the best when people in our life'

stopwords = ['he', 'the', 'our']

contains_stopwords = set() # The set data structure guarantees there won't be any duplicate
normal_words = []

for word in text.split():
    if word in stopwords:
        contains_stopwords.add(word) 
    else:
        normal_words.append(word)

print("contains_stopwords:", contains_stopwords)
print("normal_words:", normal_words)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the list comprehention and eliminate the duplicates by creating a dictionary with keys as list values and converting it again to a list:

```
itext = 'he is the best when people in our life'

stopwords = ['he', 'the', 'our']

split_words = itext.split(' ')
contains_stopwords = list(dict.fromkeys([word for word in split_words if word in stopwords]))
normal_words = list(dict.fromkeys([word for word in split_words if word not in stopwords]))

print("contains_stopwords:", contains_stopwords)
print("normal_words:", normal_words)
```

Comment: This won't work, you will have duplicates in the contains_stopwords list if the initial string contains the same stopword multiple times

Comment: You're right. I didn't catch that there should not be any duplicates. I've fixed it above

Answer (score 0):

Some list comprehension could work and then use `set()` to remove duplicates from the list. I reconverted the set datastructure to a list as per your question, but you can leave it as a set:

```py
text = 'he is the best when people in our life he he he'
stopwords = ['he', 'the', 'our']

list1 = {item for item in text.split(" ") if item in stopwords}
list2 = [item for item in text.split(" ") if item not in list1]
```

Output:

```
list1 - ['he', 'the', 'our']
list2 - ['is', 'best', 'when', 'people', 'in', 'life']
```

Comment: your first list comprehension is more complex than it should, replace by `list1 = [item for item in text.split() if item in stopwords]`

Comment: Yeah that's true, I had that then wanted to make it more specific in case it grabbed "comment" with a stopword of "men" but that isn't the case. Updated

Comment: Furthermore, if I may add, it would be nicer to use a `set` data structure instead of a `list` for `list_1`, you're adding an external dependency when using `np.unique`. In fact, you could just use a set comprehension

Comment: I answer questions to both help others and hope that others correct me on my bad practices, so I appreciate all of the comments. Thank you. Updated with your suggestions.

Comment: Your welcome ! I am no Python pro but hope it helped !

Answer (score 0):

you seem to have chosen the most difficult path. The code under should do the trick.

```
for word in text.split():
    if word in stopwords:
        contains_stopwords.append(word)
    else:
        normal_words.append(word)
```

First, we separate the text into a list of words using `split`, then we iterate and check if that word is in the list of stopwords (yeah, python allows you to do this). If it is, we just append it to the list of stopwords, if not, we append it to the other list.

Answer (score 0):

```py
text = 'he is the best when people in our life'

# I will suggest make `stopwords` a set
# cuz the membership operator(ie. in) will take O(1)
stopwords = set(['he', 'the', 'our'])

contains_stopwords = []
normal_words = []
for word in text.split():
    if word in stopwords:  # here checking membership
        contains_stopwords.append(word)
    else:
        normal_words.append(word)

print("contains_stopwords:", contains_stopwords)
print("normal_words:", normal_words)
```